# Missing definitions in old document

Tags: poetry, critical, missing

I am trying to resuscitate an old LaTeX document containing a critical edition of poetry. I have got all the packages to load, but it's missing some definitions which I think may once have been part of an older edition of Edmac or one of the other packages. Specifically, it is missing (Undefined control sequence) these commands so far:

```
\pp
\fours
\mlshift
```

I tried to get \listfiles to get me chapter-and-verse, but it won't list anything; so I extracted this from the .log file. It is loading the following:

```
inputenc.sty
fontenc.sty
tipa.sty
fontenc.sty
edmacfss.sty
oldstyle.sty
needspace.sty
ulem.sty
picins.sty
graphicx.sty
keyval.sty
graphics.sty
trig.sty
infwarerr.sty
ltxcmds.sty
verse.sty
pdftexcmds.sty
ifluatex.sty
ifpdf.sty
epstopdf-base.sty
grfext.sty
kvdefinekeys.sty
kvoptions.sty
kvsetkeys.sty
etexcmds.sty
```

If anyone with a long memory could point me in the right direction for those commands, I can try to reconstruct the document.

EDIT: some context: this is preceded by the `\input` of two files full of LaTeX preamble setting up the packages mentioned above, and then a huge chunk of manual `\long\def`s with changes to `\catcode` to force stuff into a ToC, and then the text kicks off with this (the `\pp` etc causing the problems are towards the end of this snippet).

```
\setline{0}
\prose
\pstart
\noindent  `An Poc ar Buile': duine des na Coultaisí%
\sfootnote{`Coultaisí' = \textit{Colthursts}.}
 ab ea é seo, duine des na céad Rudairí\sfootnote{Rudairí .i.\ `ridirí'.}
 a tháinig go Baile Mhúirne. Bhí sé 'na
 chónaí i dtigh na Cille. Bhí na feirmeoirí go léir fé lais
 aige agus aon chailín deas d'inín a bheadh ag éinne acu,
 chaithfeadh saé\sfootnote{`saé' \textit{sic} LS.}
 í a chuir ag\sfootnote{`ag' \textit{sic} LS.}
 triall air i gcomhair na hoíche
 dá gcuirfeadh sé fios uirthi.
 Bhí feirmeoir 'na chónaí ar an
 dtaobh thiar de ag bun Faill na
 gCórdaraí\sfootnote{`Faill na gCórdraíz' \textit{SeanAÍL},
 lgh 111, 337; `an Fhaill' \textit{SPÍC}, lch 81.}
 agus do bhí cailín ana-dheas d'inín aige agus do chuir
 sé fios uirthi lá chun teacht i gcomhair na hoíche.
 D'fhonn %*** sic LS
 gan dul \fvar{a'}{a\xout{g}} triall air, nuair a tháinig titim %sic
 na hoíche
 uirthi d'éalaigh sí leis \fvar{a'}{a\xout{n}} mbuachaill aimsire agus
 chuireadar an Bóna Bán\sfootnote{Féach \textit{SeanAÍL} agus
 \textit{SPÍC}, innéacsanna na logainmneacha.}
 siar suas díobh.
 \pend

 \pstart
 Do deineadh amhrán dò ansan mar gheall air féin agus ar
 mhnáibh agus seo mar a bhí véarsa dhe:
 \pend

 \bigskip
 \pp \fours \firstlinenum=16
 \mlshift{1em}{leis an inín óig seo Dhiarmaid a' Churraigh,}

 \stanza
 Tá formad \fvar{muar}{mór} ag Nóra Chróinnigh&
 leis an inín óig seo Dhiarmaid \fvar{a'}{a\xout{n}} Churraigh,&
 mar 'sí do fuair an cóiriú cóir&
 ón rudaire\sfootnote{.i.\ `ridire'.} óg ag bun na Cille.\&

 \noindent Aililiú, puililiú, aililiú, an poc ar buile.
 \bigskip
```

Plus, if it's any help, digging back through the files, there are other commands in the `\pp` style: `grep \\\\pp * | tr '\\ ' ' \012' | tr -d ' '|grep '^pp' | sort|uniq -c|sort -k 1nr`

```
 92 pppp
 17 pp
 17 ppcp
  3 ppicipp
  2 ppppp
  1 pp
  1 ppicp
  1 ppil
  1 ppl
  1 pppppp
  1 ppppxl
```

///Peter

Comment: Do you know an approximate time when document was working?

Comment: I think late 90s or early 2000s

Comment: can you show the use of the commands in context we can probably guess a definition

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I edited the original to add a chunk of context.

Comment: I have managed to deduce the likely meaning of `\fours` and `\mlshift`: they help calculate linewidths and formatting positions. But the `\pp` and related commands are still undefined. `\pp` only occurs once per document, near the start, so I suspect it's some kind of "begin poetry" indicator.

Comment: If your file is indeed EDMAC, which is what it seems to be, remember that EDMAC is a format, not  LaTeX style package.